# How to open with a zip with a python program?

Tags: python, windows, open-with

I wanted to program something where I can right click on a zip, do open with, and use my python program does something. How can I do that, that it knows what the path of the zip is when I do open with?

Comment: I guess the OP is not asking how to process a zip file (yet), but how to associate a zip file to a python script on File Explorer.

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962157/open-with-a-file-on-windows-with-a-python-application) will help you.